# FOR UPDATE OF, Cursor lock

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, cursor

I've run into trouble, I've tried everything ( in my oppinion, of course it's wrong 'cause the answer is out there)

The code block updates all the necessery rows in the proposed_raises table, although it should update the proposed_new_salary field with different values, because the cursor retrieves six different values for e.salary.

The code:

```
DECLARE
CURSOR cur_rai_sal (p_salary_num NUMBER) IS
   SELECT e.employee_id, e.department_id, e.salary
      FROM employees e, proposed_raises rs
         WHERE e.salary <= p_salary_num
           FOR UPDATE OF rs.date_proposed, rs.date_approved, rs.proposed_new_salary    NOWAIT;              

BEGIN
FOR v_cur_rai_sal IN cur_rai_sal(5000) LOOP

   --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_cur_rai_sal.employee_id ||''||v_cur_rai_sal.department_id|| ' ' || v_cur_rai_sal.salary);
UPDATE proposed_raises
SET date_proposed = SYSDATE,
    date_approved = NULL,
    proposed_new_salary = v_cur_rai_sal.salary /100*105
WHERE CURRENT OF cur_rai_sal;

END LOOP;
END;
```

No error messages, only "1 row(s) updated".

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what your problem is.  I wrote some similar code using a table defined like this:

```
create table t1 (id int, val number);
insert into t1 select rownum, rownum*1000 from user_objects where rownum < 10;

SQL> select * from t1;

        ID        VAL
---------- ----------
         1       1000
         2       2000
         3       3000
         4       4000
         5       5000
         6       6000
         7       7000
         8       8000
         9       9000
DECLARE
   CURSOR c (p_salary_num NUMBER) IS
      SELECT id, val
      FROM t1
      FOR UPDATE OF val  NOWAIT;
BEGIN
   FOR v_c IN c(5000) LOOP
      UPDATE t1
      SET val = v_c.val /100*105
      WHERE CURRENT OF c;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

and it worked fine:

```
SQL> select * from t1;

        ID        VAL
---------- ----------
         1       1050
         2       2100
         3       3150
         4       4200
         5       5250
         6       6300
         7       7350
         8       8400
         9       9450
```

However you must be doing something different, because your code would never produce the message "1 row(s) updated", it would say "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed."  So it appears that you are performing a stand-alone UPDATE statement not in a PL/SQL block.

Comment: I'm using Oracle Apex as a part on my studies and it gives me the message mentioned, maybe it 'cause of that.
Although that is what makes the issue hard for me, would there be a error message or some obvious fault in the code but according to my knowledge and materials it should work without any issues.

Comment: The main differece seems to be that my code has to take the value from the first table, then use it to update a second table rows.

Comment: Do you mean that you are running your code in the SQL Workshop's command window?  OK, I see that that does issue the misleading "1 row(s) updated" message after running the PL/SQL block, but it should still work.  But I'm not really clear in what way yours doesn't work?

Comment: I got it, I had to add WHERE e.salary <= p_salary_num AND e.employee_id = rs.employee_id . Although it was my understanding that the WHERE CURRENT OF was supposed to update the field the cursor is currently on, which would exluce the need for the e.ID = rs.ID part.

Comment: No, WHERE CURRENT OF does not perform the join for you, it just says "update the row of this table associated with the current row fetched from the cursor".

Comment: @Novice - Check out the Merge statement. No need for PL/SQL at all. Also, your join is incorrect, unless this was your idea. You are not joining tables.

Comment: This is for school and it's supposed to be in PL/SQL, I read that one should prefer SQL is possible.
The statement should take salary value from employees, and according to that update the proposed_raises table. I guess it doesn't count as joining?